# I need to decrease first n elements of an array by 1

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to decrease the first n-elements in an array by 1. I tried this but its not working

```
int n = 3;

for(int i = 0 ; i <array.length;i++) {

        while(i<=n){

         array[i]-=1;
         }          

}
```

Comment: umm why not `i < n` in your for loop and get rid of your while loop. Otherwise your `i` in the while loop is never incremented and thus itll be stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say `n=3`

```java
int n =3;

for(i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    array[i]-=1;
}
```

Alternatively as @locus2k points out we can also iterate through the array starting at the 0th index as so

```java
int n = 3;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    array[i]-=1;
}
```

Comment: why not `for(i = 0; i < n; i++)`

Comment: True, i was just thinking more of what the OP wanted the first `n` so `0-n`